# Redirect usando .htaccess (Apache2)

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Estoy utilizando un servidor Ubuntu server 16.04 y funciona con Apache2

Estoy intento hacer lo siguiente:

Cuando un usuario visite mi url `cdn.mywebsite.com` el `.htaccess` actúe y devuelva `192.168.12.14/`

Visitante -> cdn.mywebsite.com -> 192.168.12.14/

Estoy utilizando este código para las redirecciones

```
Redirect 302 / http://192.168.12.14/
```

Funciona perfectamente pero lo que quiero conseguir es que el visitante en su barra de direcciones no vea la dirección IP `192.168.12.14/` si no que se mantenga `cdn.mywebsite.com`

¿Como podría hacerlo? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La redirección ocurre a nivel de navegador. No hay manera de lograr lo que pides utilizando una redirección.

Por tanto, la respuesta directa a tu pregunta es:

### No

**no se puede** lograr que, haciendo una redirección, el navegador mantenga la dirección anterior en la barra de direcciones.

### Otras alternativas:

Sin embargo, si es posible lograr lo que buscas, de diferentes maneras, por ejemplo *empotrando* el sitio destino en un html vacío que reside en tu servidor, o también recibir una petición http en un servidor y *procesar* dicha petición en otro servidor. Para darte una respuesta 100% efectiva, sin embargo, haría falta saber más detalles de cómo quieres/necesitas que funcione todo el tema. Dado que eso escapa al alcance de esta respuesta, te sugiero leer sobre:

- [tag iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) (en inglés)
- [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (en inglés)
- [squid reverse proxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy) (en inglés)
- [server side load balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)#Server-Side_Load_Balancers) (en inglés)